# How to mock which return type is 'async Task<(IList<ModelClass>, PaginationModel)>'?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

My mock setup are like below

```
public class LicensePathControllerTest
{
  private MockRepository mockRepository;
}
public LicensePathControllerTest()
{
 this.mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
 this.mockIJobLicensePathService = 
 this.mockRepository.Create<IJobLicensePathService>();
 this.mockLog = this.mockRepository.Create<ILog>();
}
private LicensePathController CreateLicensePathController()
{
  return new LicensePathController(
this.mockIJobLicensePathService.Object,this.mockLog.Object);
}
```

My method is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLicensePath([FromBody] PathSearch pathSearch)
{
    var (paths, pagination) = await _pathService.GetJobPathByFilters(pathSearch); //need to mock this line.
    return ok(new OkResponse<IList<JobLicensePath>>(licensePaths, pagination.PageNumber, pagination.PageSize, pagination.TotalPages, pagination.TotalCount));
}
```

my service class method returning as well

```
public async Task<(IList<JobLicensePath>, PaginationModel)> GetJobPathByFilters(PathSearch pathSearch)
{
    //...
    IEnumerable<JobLicensePath> objJobLicensePath = null;
    objJobLicensePath = await _baseRepository.GetAsync<JobLicensePath>(filter: expression, null, null, skip: skipVal, take: take, false);
    return (objJobPath.ToList(), new PaginationModel(pageNumber, pageSize, totalCount));
}
```

I am trying to mock like below few trials but which all are not setup.

**First Try**

```
mockIJobLicensePathService
   .Setup(x => x.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()))
   .Returns(Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<Task(IList<JobLicensePath>, PaginationModel)>()));
```

> The type arguments for method 'Task.FromResult(TResult)'
> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
> explicitly.

**Second Try**

```
mockIJobLicensePathService
    .Setup(x => x.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<IList<JobLicensePath>, PaginationModel>()>));
```

> Using the generic method 'It.IsAny()' requires 1 type
> arguments

```
mockIJobLicensePathService
   .Setup(x => x.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()))
   .Returns(Task.FromResult(It.IsAny<IList<JobLicensePath>>(), It.IsAny<PaginationModel>()));
```

> No overload for method 'FromResult' takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods of the `It` class, like `Is` or `IsAny`, should be used only inside the `Setup` method.

They help you specify when your mock should "trigger".

If your method returns with a `Task` then you have several options

#### `ReturnAsync`

```
var expectedJobLicensePaths = ...;
var expectedPaginationModel = ...;

mockIJobLicensePathService
   .Setup(x => x.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()))
   .ReturnsAsync((expectedJobLicensePaths, expectedPaginationModel));
```

#### `Result` + `Return`

Since 4.16 you can [rewrite the above setup to this](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#async-methods)

```
var expectedJobLicensePaths = ...;
var expectedPaginationModel = ...;

mockIJobLicensePathService
   .Setup(x => x.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()).Result)
   .Returns((expectedJobLicensePaths, expectedPaginationModel));
```

Comment: Thanks Peter Csala, got it by sending fake parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[It.IsAny](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#type-matchers-moq-413) is used to check the method's parameter.
You can mock it like this:

```
// arrange
(IList<JobLicensePath>, PaginationModel) result = (new List<JobLicensePath>(), new PaginationModel());
var mock = new Mock<IPathService>();
mock
    .Setup(s => s.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(result));
```

Comment: It means your test invokes any mock method which was not set up. Do you see any MockException like:

'Moq.MockException : xxx invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.'

Comment: yes it was bnet.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReturnsAsync method of Moq as shown below.

```
// arrange

// Create the dummy object or use the existing one if already exists as part of your mock setup.
IList<JobLicensePath> jobLicensePath = new List<JobLicensePath>();
PaginationModel paginationModel = new PaginationModel();


mockIJobLicensePathService
      .Setup(x => x.GetJobPathByFilters(It.IsAny<PathSearch>()))
      .ReturnsAsync((jobLicensePath, paginationModel));
```